# Import APK on Play Store

Tags: android, upload, google-play, apk

I have some difficulties while importing my first APK on Play Store. A simple WebView App.

I have this error message :

> Importation error.
>   The domain name "https://chimeria.net" you specified is not valid
>   Enter a valid domain name.

*Where https://chimeria.net is the url of the embeded website in the WebView...*

After the documentation I read (https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started):

- I created a json file at 
  https://chimeria.net/.well-known/assetlinks.json

I took the SHA256 value from My Developer play store page, at the tab Application Signature.

[screenshot of where i picked up the SHA546 KEY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8rS9.png)

- I added this line in the AndroidManifest.xml of the app:

```html
<meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
```

- I added this in the res/values/strings.xml file of the app

```html
<string name="asset_statements">
      [{
        \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.share_location\"],
        \"target\": {
          \"namespace\": \"web\",
          \"site\": \"https://chimeria.net\"
        }
      }]
    </string>
```

- Later in my manifest file, I declared

```html
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="https://chimeria.net" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

- The app was created with Android Studio (Android App Bundle) that gave me an .aab file.

No matter what I tried, my app was refused because the link was not accepted.
And finnaly I wasted all possible attemple in a day.
Would somebody know what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: `android:host="https://chimeria.net"` should **NOT** have the `https://`

Comment: https is the scheme.  The host is chimeria.net.  And that needs to be changed on both data tags (the one without a host needs one)

Comment: Thank you, it was that.
For good measure, I removed https:// prefix from all "android:host" in the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chimeria.net` is the host, `https` or `http` is the scheme.

You probably want to change your manifest to:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="chimeria.net" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="chimeria.net" />
</intent-filter>
```